# Laravel whereHas is works as INNER JOIN?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I use `whereHas` in Laravel to build query:

```
})->whereHas('results', function ($query) use ($issued, $mode, $request) {

            if (($request->get("filter"))) {
                $query->where('issued', 0);
            }

        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate();
```

This quesry returns zero rows because there are now rows in table `results` for

```
 $query->where('issued', 0);
```

How to do that `whereHas` works as `LEFT JOIN`? Now it works as `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Does Laravel support `LeftJoin` closure like `whereHas`?

Comment: You say you have no rows in results table with `issued`=0, so you should not have any rows returned which is correct.  What is the behavior you are wanting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`whereHas` only returns models that have the relation you are looking for.  If you just want to limit the `Results` that are returned, try `with`:

```
$models = Model::with(['results' => function($query){

    $query->where('issued', 0);

}])->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work, I traved query it always returns data